# Failed to find any class that implements connector and which name matches FileStreamSource

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I following the Kafka quick start guide. I'm stuck as step 6 though, Import/Export your data as streams of Events...

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/

The error indicates that Kafka can't find the connector. I've added it to the connect-standalone.properties file in a variety of ways. Here is how I currently have it.

```
plugin.path=/home/ben/kafka/kafka_2.12-3.2.0/lib/connect-file-3.2.0.jar
```

I also tried pointing only to the libs folder.

I stopped the services and server, and restarted them as the guide instructs. Then I try to start the two connectors which read and write to the files.

```
bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-file-source.properties config/connect-file-sink.properties
```

But it won't start, and gives me this error.

```
[2022-06-18 18:06:16,006] ERROR Failed to create job for config/connect-file-source.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:107)
[2022-06-18 18:06:16,020] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:117)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches FileStreamSource, available connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector', version='3.2.0', encodedVersion=3.2.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector', version='3.2.0', encodedVersion=3.2.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector', version='3.2.0', encodedVersion=3.2.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector', version='3.2.0', encodedVersion=3.2.0, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector', version='3.2.0', encodedVersion=3.2.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector', version='3.2.0', encodedVersion=3.2.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector', version='3.2.0', encodedVersion=3.2.0, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector', version='3.2.0', encodedVersion=3.2.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}
```

So it seems I'm not pointing the properties to the connector correctly, although, among the variety of ways I'd tried, I also  tried the relative path the guide instructs.

This is a new Ubuntu installation running Java 11. What am I missing here?

Comment: You shouldn't need to edit the plugin path. The file connectors are on the classpath by default

Comment: I tried commenting out the plugin path in connection-standard.properties. Is that what you mean? I get the same error.

Comment: When I add the libs path to the plugin.path in side connect-standalone.properties, a similar error appears, but with the reason "Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches FileStreamSource"

Comment: In the startup logs, do you see it attempting to add the file connectors?

Answer (score 3):

just add

```
plugin.path=libs/connect-file-3.4.0.jar
```

in your config/connect-standalone.properties file.

Comment: It might be obvious, but replace the version number with yours

Answer (score 2):

This answer builds off @John's answer to provide a reference for those facing this issue on macOS Ventura with a Kafka installation done through Homebrew. For context, I encountered this error when trying to run a `FileStreamSource` connector example from Chapter 3 of *Kafka in Action*. In order to solve this issue, I made a copy of the file `opt/homebrew/opt/kafka/libexec/config/connect-standalone.properties`, edited the new file to have an additional key-value pair of `plugin.path=/opt/homebrew/opt/kafka/libexec/libs` and then invoked the `connect-standalone` binary on my `PATH` with that edited properties file as the first argument instead of my Kafka installation's default `connect-standalone.properties` file.

Answer (score 1):

For confluent-7.2.2 the FileStreamSource connector is in the folder `/share/filestream-connectors`. Adding that to my `plugin.path` worked for me.

Comment: For me it worked adding `/usr/share/filestream-connectors` to `plugin.path`

Answer (score 0):

Look at:

> ./bin/kafka-run-class.sh:regex="(-(test|test-sources|src|scaladoc|javadoc).jar|jar.asc|connect-file.*.jar)$"

I don't know the details, but connect-file is excluded in the class path. Simply editing kafka-run-class.sh did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still having this problem, `FileStreamSourceConnector` and `FileStreamSinkConnector`, have been removed from the default classpath.To use them in Kafka Connect standalone or distributed mode they need to be explicitly added, for example
`CLASSPATH=./lib/connect-file-3.2.0.jar ./bin/connect-distributed.sh`.

[See official documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect_plugindiscovery:%7E:text=The%20example%20connectors%2C%20FileStreamSourceConnector%20and%20FileStreamSinkConnector%2C%20have%20been%20removed%20from%20the%20default%20classpath.%20To%20use%20them%20in%20Kafka%20Connect%20standalone%20or%20distributed%20mode%20they%20need%20to%20be%20explicitly%20added%2C%20for%20example%20CLASSPATH%3D./lib/connect%2Dfile%2D3.2.0.jar%20./bin/connect%2Ddistributed.sh.).